# Cokernel of $A - \lambda I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix and let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ such that there is exactly one eigenvector $v$ associated to $\lambda$. Then $A - \lambda I$ has nullity $1$ and rank $n-1$.

If we assume that $A$ is the matrix of some linear transformation on a space $V$, then the cokernel of $A - \lambda I$ is quotient $V / im(A - \lambda I)$. Since the nullity is $1$, then this quotient has dimension $1$. Let $u$ be a vector in this cokernel. **How are $u$ and $v$ related?**

All I have been able to determine is that if $A$ is a projection, then the cokernel is isomorphic to the kernel. Also, the orthogonal complement of the image is contained in the cokernel but I can't determine whether it is equal to it in general.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that the orthogonal complement of the image is contained in the cokernel since they are not subspaces of the same vector space. Perhaps you're really interested in the orthogonal complement $\operatorname{im}(A - \lambda I)^\perp$.

Comment: For an $n \times n$ matrix, the cokernel is always isomorphic to the kernel, as can seen by considering the dimensions of these spaces. It's not clear what you mean by "the orthogonal complement of the image is contained in the cokernel".

Answer (score 1):

So that we can compare elements of the kernel and cokernel, I'll assume that $V$ is an inner product space. With that, the $\operatorname{im}(A - \lambda I)^\perp$ can canonically be identified with the cokernel $V/(\operatorname{Im}(A - \lambda I))$. With that, your question becomes: how is $u \in \ker(A - \lambda I)$ related to $v \in \operatorname{Im}(A - \lambda I)^\perp$?

Note first of all that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^*$, the adjoint of $A$. Indeed:
$$
\langle v, (A - \lambda I)x \rangle \quad \text{for all } x \implies\\
\langle (A - \lambda I)^*v,x \rangle \quad \text{for all } x \implies\\
(A - \lambda I)^*v = 0 \implies A v = \bar \lambda v.
$$
Another point is that if $v$ is an element of $\operatorname{Im}(A - \mu I)^\perp$ for $\mu \neq \lambda$, then $v^Tu = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is not entirely clear to me why the cokernel is exactly equal to the orthogonal complement of the image of $A - \lambda I$. Could you please explain that? Further, it is clear that the cokernel and the kernel are isomorphic since they have the same dimension. However, I guess my question is: is there a canonical isomorphism between the two?

Comment: To your first question, the map $v \mapsto v + \operatorname{Im}(A - \lambda I)$ is a "canonical" isomorphism. Regarding your second question, I strongly suspect not but I don't know how to disprove the existence of a canonical isomorphism.